# Get data from adjacent columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a grading spreadsheet and i want to find the student who got the highest number of marks

Steps are

1)Find the Max number of marks
This one was easy  ; =MAX(F6:F11)

2)Get the cell ID where the max number is found (For e.g C4)

3)Show the ADJACENT Cell details  ( A4  & B4)

How can i achieve the second and third part

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so if I understand your data layout correctly you have:

```
CellDetails1(Column A)     CellDetails2(B)     Cell ID(C)     Something(D)     Something(E)     Marks(F)
Test1                      Test2               1              blah             blah             99
Test3                      Test4               2              blah             blah             98
Test5                      Test6               3              blah             blah             100
```

Now where ever you want to put your three formulas for Cell ID, CellDetails1(Column A) and CellDetails2(B) you would have these formulas

**ID**

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(MAX(F:F),F:F,0))
```

would return 3

**CellDetails1 (A)**

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(F:F),F:F,0))
```

would return Test5

**CellDetails2 (B)**

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAX(F:F),F:F,0))
```

would return Test 6

Here's a great explanation of how the index and match formulas work separately and together, http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/

Comment: Also a good resource for Index. I think I may have learned a thing or two from that article :)